# Nodemailer envia e-mail mas destinatário não o recebe (servidor hostgator)

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

Tenho um servidor de e-mails no hostgator e uma conta no mesmo. Preciso usar o nodemailer para enviar mensagens para os meus clientes a partir desta conta. Para isso preciso configurar manualmente com essas instruções do hostgator

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já testei todas as combinações possíveis de HOST x PORT no meu código fonte. Todas elas retornam falha de envio, a única configuração que envia o e-mail é esta.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host:"br688.hostgator.com.br",
    port:"465",
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'atendimento@assistencia-macoffice.com',
        pass: 'XXXXX'
    }
})
```

No entanto o e-mail não chega ao destinatário, já tentei enviar para diversos e-mails diferentes em varios serviços.

Comment: Verifique se eles nao bloquearam os serviços de mail. Geralmente  o fazem para evitar spammers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Digital Ocean por padrão bloqueia qualquer envio de e-mail conectado a servidor externo. Logo, se você usa alguma API pra se conectar via SMTP a uma conta do Google, por exemplo, o Digital Ocean não irá permitir. Eles fazem isso para evitar a criação de serviços de spammer.

Caso você solicite, eles poderão fazer o desbloqueio sem problemas, desde que você envie uma mensagem explicando qual o intuito do envio de e-mails, descrevendo em detalhes o objetivo do serviço.

O problema é que mesmo você fazendo isso, ainda é possível enfrentar um novo bloqueio mais cedo ou mais tarde, por parte do provedor de e-mail (ex.: gmail), que não permite o envio automático (via API) de um número excessivo de e-mails.

A maneira que eu recomendo é utilizar o serviço Mailgun (mailgun.com), com ele, você pode mandar até 10.000 mensagens mensais sem custo algum. E ainda pode acompanhar tudo o que é enviado, inclusive tendo estatísticas de cliques, visualizações, criação de campanhas, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Tive o mesmo problema, adicionei o parâmetro "name" no createTransport e funciounou. O e-mail ainda é reconhecido como span quando as pessoas recebem, estou tentando resolver esse problema (isso se for possível), segue o exemplo:

```
let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  name: 'no-reply@dominio.com.br',
  host:'mail.dominio.com.br',
  service:'mail.dominio.com.br',
  port:465,
  secure:true,
auth:{
    user: 'no-reply@dominio.com.br',
    pass:'pas123'
}});
```

Consegui resolver utilizando a sugestão desse outro post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305050/nodemailer-email-send-but-not-receive

Comment: De fato isso funcionou, mas o atributo 'name' está deprecated e é arriscado utiliza-lo.

Answer (score 3):

Tive um problema com digital ocean que bloqueava a porta SMTP. O email saia beleza mas não era enviado.
Pedi um suporte e eles liberatam. Já era.